# Select postgres entre dois valores

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Estou a desenvolver um sistema e preciso realizar um select para buscar o % taxa que um cliente tera.

Primeiro eu verifico qual o % de devolução de cheques deste cliente e busco em outra tabela qual a taxa pré-definida que ele terá direito a partir deste % de devolução.

Um exemplo de um registro na tabela que preciso buscar:

```
id | descricao        | per_min | per_max | taxa_proposta | taxa_desconto
1  | De 0,00% a 2,00% | 0.00    | 2.00    | 100.00        | 0.75 
2  | De 2,01% a 4,00% | 2.01    | 4.00    | 73.40         | 0.55
```

Ou sejá quando o % de devolução do cliente for entre 0% e 2% preciso pegar o a taxa_proposta e taxa_desconto do ID 1 e se for entre 2,01% a 4,00% preciso pegar os valores do ID 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que você tenha uma estrutura como essa:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    id BIGINT,
    id_cliente BIGINT,
    taxa_devolucao REAL
);

INSERT INTO tb_devolucao ( id, id_cliente, taxa_devolucao ) VALUES ( 1, 100, 1.25 );
INSERT INTO tb_devolucao ( id, id_cliente, taxa_devolucao ) VALUES ( 2, 200, 3.33 );

CREATE TABLE tb_foobar
(
    id BIGINT,
    descricao TEXT,
    per_min REAL,
    per_max REAL,
    taxa_proposta REAL,
    taxa_desconto REAL
);

INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, descricao, per_min, per_max, taxa_proposta, taxa_desconto ) VALUES ( 1, 'De 0,00% a 2,00%', 0.00, 2.00, 100.0, 0.75 );
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, descricao, per_min, per_max, taxa_proposta, taxa_desconto ) VALUES ( 2, 'De 2,01% a 4,00%', 2.01, 4.00, 73.40, 0.55 );
```

Você pode recuperar a `taxa_proposta` e a `taxa_desconto` de um dado cliente a partir da sua `taxa_devolucao` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
    fb.*
FROM
    tb_foobar AS fb
JOIN
    tb_devolucao AS dev ON ( dev.taxa_devolucao BETWEEN fb.per_min AND fb.per_max )
WHERE
    dev.id_cliente = 200;
```

Teste no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e5184/1)

Answer (score -1):

Acabei resolvendo a minha situação, encontrei no Stack Inglês neste link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467298/how-to-correctly-use-fetch-first-in-postgresql

Resolvi desta forma:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    nome_tabela
WHERE
    per_max >= 2.01
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Esta query me retorna os valores do ID 2 o que estaria correto para este caso.

Answer (score -1):

Estou levando em consideração que você vai passar o valor do **Percentual de devolução do cliente** para este select, ou se necessitar poderá fazer oj Joins Necessários.

```
SELECT id,taxa_proposta,taxa_desconto 
      FROM taxa_pre_definida 
          WHERE __Percentual de devolução do cliente__ 
               BETWEEN per_min AND per_max
```

Com a utilização do BETWEEN, você poderá vê se o percentual informado está neste intervalo per_min até per_max se tiver ele irá retornar a linha encontrada.

Espero ter ajudado.